# makefile is hiding the output but when i run command directly it shows full output

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

When I run the command without make command i get this output

```
[GIN-debug] GET    /internal/login           --> myproject/app_demo.AppHandler.InternalLogin-fm (7 handlers)
[GIN-debug] POST   /wp/index                 --> myproject/wp_demo.indexHandler (6 handlers)
[GIN-debug] POST   /wp/single                --> myproject/wp_demo.singleHandler (6 handlers)
[GIN-debug] POST   /wp/posts                 --> myproject/wp_demo.postsHandler (6 handlers)
[GIN-debug] POST   /wp/counts                --> myproject/wp_demo.countsHandler (6 handlers)
[GIN-debug] POST   /wp/get_options           --> myproject/wp_demo.getOptionsHandler (6 handlers)
[GIN-debug] POST   /cful/index               --> myproject/cful_demo.indexHandler (6 handlers)
[GIN-debug] POST   /cful/single              --> myproject/cful_demo.singleHandler (6 handlers)
[GIN-debug] POST   /cful/posts               --> myproject/cful_demo.postsHandler (6 handlers)
[GIN-debug] POST   /cful/counts              --> myproject/cful_demo.countsHandler (6 handlers)
[GIN-debug] POST   /cms/index                --> myproject/cms_demo.CmsHandler.indexHandler-fm (7 handlers)
[GIN-debug] POST   /cms/single               --> myproject/cms_demo.CmsHandler.singleHandler-fm (7 handlers)
[GIN-debug] POST   /cms/posts                --> myproject/cms_demo.CmsHandler.postsHandler-fm (7 handlers)
[GIN-debug] POST   /cms/counts               --> myproject/cms_demo.CmsHandler.countsHandler-fm (7 handlers)
2022/12/29 12:17:54 Http Sever started at http://localhost:2111
[GIN-debug] [WARNING] You trusted all proxies, this is NOT safe. We recommend you to set a value.
Please check https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#readme-don-t-trust-all-proxies for details.
[GIN-debug] Listening and serving HTTP on :2111
```

But i run the command using `make watch`

I get this only

```
➜  myproject git:(main) ✗ make watch
2022/12/29 12:18:23 Http Sever started at http://localhost:2111
```

How do i print the full output when running commands using makefile

Here's the Makefile

```
hello:
    @echo "Hello, Mango"

watch:
    @echo `air`
```

Comment: You say "when I run the command" but you don't say what command you are running.

Comment: `make watch` i showed already on the example above

Comment: No.  The first sentence in your question is "when I run the command without make command" and then you show the "correct" output.  But you don't say what command you ran "without make", to get the correct output.

Comment: I made it work. I was using the @echo command and now i have removed it and it shows the full output of the running command. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I suspected that hence my question.  Many tools will generate different output if they are writing to a terminal, versus another program (using either pipelines `|` or backticks etc.)

Answer (score 0):

As you found recipes that start with `@` are silent (see also .SILENT).  You can modify your Makefile as you did to reverse that.  If the version of make you has the `--trace` option (version 4.3 does for instance) then it will print the entire recipe even if they are normally silent.

Comment: I get this error `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make: unrecognized option `--trace'` when i use trace

Comment: I added the version caveat .  You could try -d aka --debug=all but it's rather noisy.